# java libraries to do FTP operations

Tags: ftp, java

I have a set of deployment based activities that also involve

1. do FTP transfers from dev machine to linux based server, and
2. execute certain scripts on the linux box.

It could be possible to automate these activities by creating a small java based utility that does these FTP activities.

Here are my questions:

1. is there java library to perform FTP operations (like apache commons net, http://commons.apache.org/net/)?
2. Is there opensource libraries to invoke shell scripts over FTP and perform certain actions based on the script output?

Please note that I am NOT looking for solutions to my specific problem in the forum; I am more interested in looking for technology/java library alternatives and suggestions from members here.

Comment: What's wrong with Apache Commons Net?

Comment: Your second question is not entirely clear. Are you trying to execute on the server, a script that exists on the client? And where are you expecting the post-execute actions to run? The library you linked (Apache Commons Net) has most, if not all the functionality you seek. You can also take a look at [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Comment: @JamesA as I said, I want to invoke a server side shell script. Is it possible using commons net? I have not verified using commons net yet.

Comment: Invoking a server side script depends on the ftp server running on the host.  The `QUOTE` subcommand is usually the gateway to that functionality.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** we very much have apache commons net library to perform the ftp operations.

`you can view this link:`

```
                        http://commons.apache.org/net/
```

`Download the commons-net-ftp-2.0 lib from the above site.`

`I am also attaching my program to upload and download song to ftp server using the apache` `lib`

**Uploading :**

```
public void goforIt(){


        FTPClient con = null;

        try
        {
            con = new FTPClient();
            con.connect("192.168.2.57");

            if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
            {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                boolean result = con.storeFile("/vivekm4a.m4a", in);
                in.close();
                if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






    }
```

**Dowloading:**

```
public void goforIt(){
    FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("192.168.2.57");

        if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.retrieveFile("vivekm4a.m4a", out);
            out.close();
            if (result) Log.v("download result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("download result","failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar. What about invoking script at a certain server location. The idea is what I do on a putty terminal, I want to automate the process. Is this a far fetched imagination?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned PuTTY (an SSH client) you should probably look at the [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library.  It provides SSH access and would give you the ability to securely transfer files and remotely execute shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/) in a productive environment. For example it has HTTP-Proxy, SOCKS-Proxy, FTPS and FTPES support.

For executing the shell scripts you will have to use a ssh library like [these ones](http://linuxmafia.com/ssh/java.html).